# Make a clickable loop with a single TextView?

Tags: java, android

*I only just started learning XML and Java code this week, thanks to Udacity's course... I'm barely halfway through but I felt like making my own pointless app..*

So I have some black text on a red background.

When I click the text, I tell Java to change the text to white and background to blue, and it does.

When I click the text again, I want it to go back to the black and red, but it doesn't.

I know why this happens but I don't know how to fix this.
It happens because my text has an `onClick` to change the colors and display to screen. So naturally, the same `onClick` is being called on each click.

What do I do to make it constantly alternate between the two stages of colors every time it's clicked?

My XML is :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#c04"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#c04"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="Hey"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:text="Hey!"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="150sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the Java code is

```
public void displaying(String message) {
    TextView whatever = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisplay);
    whatever.setText(message);
    whatever.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    whatever.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(82, 218, 199));
}

public void Hey(View v) {
    displaying("Ho!");
}
```

I did some digging and found I could use the "onClickListener"? But no matter what I do I just couldn't get it to work. Maybe I'm unable to get the syntax right. 
Is there another method ..perhaps simpler? It seems like a fairly easy task in my head but this one really has me stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

```
public void Hey(View v) {
    TextView whatever = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisplay);
    if(whatever.getText().toString().equals("Hey!")){
         whatever.setText("Ho!");
         whatever.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
         whatever.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(82, 218, 199));
    } else if (whatever.getText().toString().equals("Ho!"){
         whatever.setText("Hey!");
         whatever.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
         whatever.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(/*red RGB*/));
    }
}
```

You decide wich text and background color you set based on the text of your TextView.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Although I had to place it in 

public void displaying(String message) 

not 

public void Hey(View v) 

But that did the trick, thanks a lot! I guess I'll go look up some if/else stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the state of your display in a boolean. Something like that (untested):

```
boolean stateOfMyTextView = true;

public void displaying(String message) {
    TextView whatever = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisplay);
    whatever.setText(message);
    if (stateOfMyTextView == true) {
        // First color
        whatever.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        whatever.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(82, 218, 199));
    }
    else {
        // Other color
        whatever.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        whatever.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)); 
    }
    // change state of the boolean
    stateOfMyTextView = !stateOfMyTextView;
}
```